# xss scripts through console of web-developers-tools

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-application, security-testing

So, well I am learning selenium webdriver, junit4. I need to know, is it a proper way to add "XSS scripts" through the console of web developers tools? 
Can anyone help me with an example ?

Comment: Welcome to SQA. Are you asking if Selenium can be used for testing cross site scripting vulnerabilities and exploits?

Comment: @Francis :  Yes, u got me rite